# Problems with directories making a simple makefile

Tags: makefile

I want to make a simple makefile for a C project that have the following directories.

```
 -Project  
   - src 
     - a.c  
     - b.c
     - main.c  
   - headers  
     - a.h  
     - b.h   
   - build  
     - makefile  
     - project.exe
```

And here it's the makefile that I've done.

```
project: a.o b.o main.o
    cc -o sesion0 a.o b.o main.o
a.o: ../src/a.c ../headers/a.h 
b.o: ../src/b.c ../headers/b.h 
main.o: ../src/main.c ../headers/a.h ../headers/b.h
```

But when I execute the **make** order, it tell's me that the file or directory a.o, b.o and main.o doesn't exist and also that there's not input files. In the end shows this error:

```
make: *** [project] Error 1
```

Does anyone know why this happen or where I have the error? I don't know very well how to manage the directories in the makefile.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Make has built-in rules for making x.o from x.c, but not from ../src/x.c. In other words, paths of input and output must be the same, only the file extension differs.

You can fix it by using [VPATH for directory search](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Directory-Search):

```
VPATH = ../src:../headers
a.o: a.c a.h 
b.o: b.c b.h 
main.o: main.c a.h b.h
```

Comment: Thanks for the anwser Maxim but know it shows me another error.
This is the error:

`cc    -c -o a.o ../src/a.c
../src/a.c:1:21: error: a.h: Don't exist the file o directory
make: *** [a.o] Error 1`

Do you know why this happen? It seems that it doesn't look for the a.h file in the ../headers directory.

Comment: Now you need to add compiler include paths. Add `CPPFLAGS=-I../headers` somewhere in your Makefile.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin the following question has the same set of issues when dealing with multiple targets and their dependencies? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30043480/make-recipe-to-prevent-rebuilding-of-non-dependent-targets#